# FUEL PUMP DIRECT CONNECTION ON HYUNDAI SONATA V6 1997

Tags: hyundai, sonata

My Hyundai Sonata engine was just cranking. On suspecting it to be fuel system I connected the pump directly to a fuse that works with ignition on. It now starts and runs very well. What effect is this going to have on my system. The fuel consumption is rather high, is this because of this direct connection?

Comment: Most fuel systems now have a variable speed fuel pump, fuel pressure is regulated this way, so connecting 12v directly to the pump is not a good idea. Either the fuel pump fuse or relay has failed, or possibly something more complicated that would have to be diagnosed by a professional.

Answer (score 1):

So as this is not the proper way to control the fuel pump, you may override some controls the car has on the efficiency of the pump(if any at all). I would first try and find what fuse or wire disconnect is causing the fuel pump to not work with its correct installation and fix the problem there instead.